# Shell script with string beginning with "-e"

Tags: shell, unix, echo, sh

```
#!/bin/sh
STR="-e"
echo ${STR}
STR="${STR} HI"
echo ${STR}
```

The above script prints out:

```
 HI
```

after a blank line. Why is this, and how do I make a string beginning with "-e"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo` is not a very good UNIX citizen. If it were well-behaved you'd be able to write `echo -- "$STR"`, with `--` indicating the end of the options list. But it's not, so you can't.

Your best bet is to use `printf` instead.

```
printf '%s\n' "$STR"
```

Comment: +1; in other words: if the argument passed to `echo` starts with one or more tokens that happen to look like valid options - like the `-e` in this case - `echo` will invariably interpret them as such.